# EF 1 to 1 required relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an attribute which looks like this:

```
public class CameraAttribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string CompatibleMemory { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string WhiteBalance { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string SceneModes { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string ShootingModes { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string PhotoEffects { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string CameraPlayback { get; set; }
    public bool Tripod { get; set; }
    public bool DirectPrinting { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Colour { get; set; }

    public CameraAttributePicture Picture { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeVideo Video { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeAudio Audio { get; set; }

    public CameraAttributeBattery Battery { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeDimension Dimensions { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeDisplay Display { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeLightExposure Exposure { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeFlash Flash { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeFocusing Focusing { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeInterface Interface { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeLens Lens { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeNetwork Network { get; set; }
    public CameraAttributeShutter Shutter { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")] public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and the **Audio** looks like this:

```
public class CameraAttributeAudio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string SupportedFormats { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AttributeId")] public CameraAttribute Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

I have set up some mapping in my DbContext like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CameraAttribute>().HasRequired(m => m.Audio).WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.Attributes).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

but when I try to run the command **add-migration** I get this error:

> CameraAttribute_Audio_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'CameraAttribute_Audio_Target' in relationship 'CameraAttribute_Audio'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

As you can see from the Attribute class all the properties throw this error.
Does anyone know why and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `CameraAttributeAudio` class has its own `Id` property as well while it is unnecessary in a one-to-one relationship because `AttributeId` can identify both the `CameraAttribute` and the `CameraAttributeAudio`. It should use the `AttributeId` as its primary `[Key]`.

```
public class CameraAttributeAudio
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Attributes")] 
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)] 
    public string SupportedFormats { get; set; }

    public CameraAttribute Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

I moved the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to the `AttributeId` property so that the annotations are in one place. Although it is also correct to have it on the `Attributes` property.